# Can websites appear differently to different internet networks?

Tags: dns, cache, error, isp

I just began launching a site for one of my clients, but I've come across a very strange issue.

Whenever the client tries to access the website from an internet capable device in his office, he gets an error page. However, I have accessed the same site from both my house and from my office on multiple devices and browsers and the correct page has always come up.

This problem has been going on for a few days now and the client says he has tried rebooting and clearing the local cache of the computers at his office.

So, I was wondering why this might be happening and, in turn, how it might be remedied.

Thanks.

Comment: What error do they get?

Comment: Is the site's domain resolving correctly?

Comment: There is not enough information to really answer this question. Can you tell us more about the network, is the website hosted externally or internally, is the local network using NAT, can it resolve the domain name, and so on. I know there are a lot of variables, but anything you can tell us will get will give us a jumping off place and a direction to go.

Answer (score 1):

If the web page is on a server in the same network as your client, and the network is behind NAT, this is the reason. Generally, one cannot access the services behind port forwarding from inside the actual network.

Solution to this problem is either setting up split-horizon DNS or hairpin NAT.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047391/nat-translation-not-working-from-inside-the-network-hairpin-condition has more details on the issue.

Comment: "one cannot access the services behind port forwarding from inside the actual network" - this is very much dependent on the hardware, some routers handle this OK; some don't.